# how do i insert inputs to find value of integrals in python?

Tags: python, input, integral

I am working a physics coursework, and I am currently stuck at this section.
I've trying but I couldn't get it right.
Really need help here.

Its about the trapezium rule,
Question: What is the value of the integral in equation  f(x)=x4*(1-x)44/(1+x^2)

this is the code I've tried, but I can not get the answer

```
from math import *

def f(x):
    f(x)=x**4*(1-x)**4/(1+x**2)
    return f(x)

def trap0 (f,a,b,n):
    h= float (b-a)/n
    s =0.5*( f(a)+f(b))
    for i in range (1,n):
        s=s+f(a+i*h)
    return s*h
```

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of `f` is bogus. This is all you need to write:

```
def f(x):
    return x**4 * (1 - x)**4 / (1 + x**2)
```

The rest of your code looks good to me, so long as you call `trap0` with floating-point arguments for `a` and `b`.

```
>>> trap0(math.cos, 0.0, math.pi/2, 100)
0.99997943823960744
```

If you want to call it with integer `a` and `b` then things can go wrong, because `f` ends up doing integer division instead of floating-point division:

```
>>> f(4.0)
1219.7647058823529
>>> f(4)
1219
```

The easiest fix to is to coerce the division to be floating-point, perhaps like this:

```
def g(x):
    return x**4 * (1 - x)**4 / (1.0 + x**2)

>>> g(4.0) == g(4)
True
```

Comment: yup, done it in python. huu but I couldn't get it right either

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import *
```

Is considered incorrect when doing imports. Granted this is just a ten minute wonder, this style of imports are frowned upon as they clutter namespaces and overwrite local variables if they are also assigned in the module or your source.

Considering you used ** over pow() means that you don't actually need the math import to begin with. But if you are on python 2.x you might want to use.

```
from __future__ import division
```

Gareth has the right answer for the function though im just complaining about style issues